# MySQL Python LIKE wildcard

Tags: python, mysql

I want to do a Python MySQL query such as:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = "select text \
       from steps \
       where text like '%start%'"
cursor.execute(sql)
```

But the % isn't seen as a wildcard, it's expecting a variable, I guess. I get an error:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Nothing seems to work. It would also be nice if I could use a variable instead of '%start%'

Answer (score 25):

I assume you're using python db-api.

You can try escaping `%` as `%%`.

As for passing the parameters there is a number of ways, for example:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = """select text 
   from steps 
   where text like %s"""
cursor.execute(sql, (('%' + 'start' + '%',))
```

You can see examples of the other ways of parameter passing [on this blog](http://coffeefreecode.wordpress.com/2008/06/28/python-db-api-korzystanie-z-relacyjnych-baz-danych-w-pythonie/) in "Interface modułu" section. Not all of them work with all connectors.

Comment: Escaping with %% works, thanks :) Use of literal strings gave the same error.

Comment: @user984003 strange, but i can't even test it right now. glad it helped anyway.

Comment: @soulcheck: String syntax has nothing to do with interpretation of `%` (unlike how Bourne Shell or Ruby interpret `$`, for example).  So `"""%start%"""` is the exact same as `"%start%"`, which is the same as `'%start%'` and `r'%start%'`, etc.

Comment: Passing the parameters didn't work. I don't get an error, but it finds 0 lines, making me think that it's not seeing the wildcards. This worked:
sql = "select text from cmt_steps where text like '%%"+start+"%%'"

Comment: The string syntax made the difference: `"""SELECT * FROM courses WHERE title like %s"""` works.